# How to use ADmad/cakephp-i18n to retrieve translated data from database based on URL

Tags: database, internationalization, translation, cakephp-3.0

i'm trying to use the ADmad/cakephp-i18n plugin with cakephp 3, i managed to get the routes and links to work but i don't know how to retrieve translated data from database, is their a specific table or table format that i should respect. any documentation or example would be helpful.

Comment: Have you read the last section of the readme (**Using the DbMessagesLoader**)? **https://github.com/ADmad/cakephp-i18n#using-the-dbmessagesloader**

Comment: thank you for your response,yes i did read the last section of the readme file, i think the **DbMessagesLoader** needs multiple domains, i have only one domain and i want to keep it that way, i want to use I18nRoute instead so i can use URLs like  **www.domain.com/en/controller/action**

Comment: The class only retrieves a single domain, if multiple domains are required at all, then only if you you are actually making use of multiple domains (`__d()`), and then it's the `I18n` class that actually needs to be configured for multiple domains. Also there is no "_instead_" here, the `I18nRoute` won't do anything other than persisting the `lang` route element, it won't affect translations/localization in any way. Using the messages loader is the essential part of the plugin that makes the translations available in the first place.